# how to pass calculate date to bash shell?

Tags: bash

I have this test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

calling it works:

```
sh ./test.sh $(date +"%F")
```

I want to subtract 5 days from current date and pass to test.sh

```
sh ./test.sh $(date --date="date-5 day" +"%F")
```

The line above does not work. What is the correct way?

Comment: You're trying to do something that can't be done without being *way* more specific, and is kind of @jon-skeet's domain: what does "minus 5 days" mean. Is it 120 hours? In which timezone? Following which calendar? In which locale? Things get rather complicated even if you "just want 5 days ago", because there is no "just" when it comes to date/time calculations. So instead of asking bash for this information, use a date/time CLI utility, or a proper date/time library from a scripting language with a solid enough such library that you can trust the results to be right.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49055/46316) - you want `--date="-5 days"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
sh ./test.sh $(date --date="-5 day" +"%F")
```

With my settings `en_US.UTF-8` command `date --date="-5 day" +"%F"` outputs `2017-08-04`.